# Lettuce and Django 1.55+ getting ImportError: cannot import name WSGIServerException

Tags: django, lettuce

Just tried integrating Lettuce into my django installation and getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/var/www/abc/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 399, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/var/www/abc/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/var/www/abc/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 272, in fetch_command
    klass = load_command_class(app_name, subcommand)
  File "/var/www/abc/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 75, in load_command_class
    module = import_module('%s.management.commands.%s' % (app_name, name))
  File "/var/www/abc/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 40, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/var/www/abc/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lettuce/django/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    from lettuce.django.server import Server
  File "/var/www/abc/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lettuce/django/server.py", line 33, in <module>
    from django.core.servers.basehttp import WSGIServerException
ImportError: cannot import name WSGIServerException
```

I heard that WSGIServerException was removed from django, so how do I get around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/releases/1.5.5/#backwards-incompatible-changes)

> The undocumented django.core.servers.basehttp.WSGIServerException has
>   been removed. Use socket.error provided by the standard library
>   instead.

i think you can tell "lettuce"'s author,0.0 .or: update "lettuce" python package.

Answer (score 3):

It's [fixed on branch master](https://github.com/gabrielfalcao/lettuce/issues/394), but it not yet available on [PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/lettuce).

You can simply install it from the source:

```
pip install -e git+https://github.com/gabrielfalcao/lettuce.git#egg=lettuce
```